# How to create different jar files within one build block in maven?

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I have a maven project that compiles two different projects and then creates classes in this dir: ${project.build.directory}/classes

Where ${project.build.directory} points to the dir that pom.xml exists.

I’m using maven-jar-plugin with different “execution” blocks to make the jar files out of related directories/classes for each project. I’m very new to maven and have difficulty to define the right “include” and “exclude” directories.

This is the structure that my classes reside:

\target\classes\com

\target\classes\com\microsoft

\target\classes\com\google

\target\classes\org

The first jar file needs to be created out of these classes:

\target\classes\com\microsoft

\target\classes\org

And the second jar needs to be created out of these classes:

\target\classes\com\google

Following is the part of “build” block that has “execution” blocks to create these jars. The first jar is called: msn-prod and the other is called: google. As you see, I’ve tried all different combinations to create these jars and none worked - they exist in the following build block as the parts which are commented.

Can somebody please help me on this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>msn-prod</id>
                    <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals> 
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>msn-prod</classifier>    
                        <!-- <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/com/microsoft</classesDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.class</include>
                        </includes> 
                        <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/org</classesDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.class</include>
                        </includes>-->   
                        <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</classesDirectory>
                        <!-- <includes>
                            <include>**/*.class</include>
                        </includes>-->                           
                        <!-- <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/com/google/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>-->                          
                        <!-- <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/google/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>-->                              
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/com/microsoft/*.class</include>
                            <include>**/org/*.class</include>
                        </includes>             
                        <finalName>${msn.prod}-${msn.api.version}</finalName>              
                    </configuration>
            </execution> 

            <execution>
                    <id>google</id>
                    <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals> 
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>google</classifier>

                        <!-- <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</classesDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/com/google/*.class</include>
                        </includes>-->                          
                        <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/com/google</classesDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.class</include>
                        </includes>                                     
                        <finalName>${google}-${google.api.version}</finalName>              
                    </configuration>
            </execution>

        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are violating the Maven best practice of one build artifact per module and therefore running into trouble. Just break it up into multiple projects and it will be easy.